# Pass different PHP variables to modal and show in form inputs

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp, bootstrap-modal, cakephp-3.0

I have a table: Users with 3 different attributes:

- ID
- firstname
- lastname

In the index.ctp page for Users, for each data entry, I have the Edit action available to use.

```
<div>
    <table class="usersTables" id="userTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('firstname') ?></th>
                <th scope="col" class="actions"><?= __('Actions') ?></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?= h($user->firstname) ?></td>                  
                <td class="actions">
                    <?= $this->Html->link(__('Edit'), ['action' => 'edit', $user->id], ['class' => 'view', 'data-id' => $user->id]) ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
         $('.edit').click(function () {
              ev.preventDefault();
              var userId = $(this).attr('data-id');
              $('#editModal').modal('show');
              alert(userId);
         });
    });
</script>

<div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                     <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                 </button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title" id="editModalLabel">Edit</h4>
                 <div>
                     <div class="col-sm-6">
                         <?= $this->Form->input('firstname', ['class' => 'form-control', 'label' => 'First Name', 'placeholder' => 'First name', 'id' => 'firstname']); ?>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-sm-6">
                         <?= $this->Form->input('lastname', ['class' => 'form-control', 'label' => 'Last Name', 'placeholder' => 'Last name', 'id' => 'lastname']); ?>
                     </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                 <button id="savebutton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Clicking the Edit button in the table first gives me an alert pop up that tells me which `$user->id` I selected, then opens up the Edit modal. However, my form inputs are still empty even though the related attributes for that specific datat entry are fileld in the database. I'm not sure how to connect the `data-id` variable that was then defined as a JavaScript variable to the form input which I believe requires a PHP variable again ($user->firstname).

If I use `'value' => $user->firstname` in the `firstname` form input, I get the data from the very last data entry every time (eg. if I have 3 data entries in my Users table, I will always get the 3rd entry's firstname).

Comment: I think you'll need to use an AJAX request to get the data related to the user id that has been clicked. Send the clicked `userId` as data from the ajax request and get its details from the response will be be further used to populate the edit form.

Comment: In https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp, the AJAX GET request has 2 parameters: URL and callback. I believe in my case, the URL would be users.json (i.e. the index page), but I'm unsure as to how I would pass the userId that has been clicked in order to retrieve the relevant data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad you researched about AJAX. First you need to create a function in your controller that will return a user's details.

```
// Just an example in the UsersController
public function userDetails($id = null) {
    $userDetails = $this->Users->find('all'['where(['id' => $id])])->first();
    $this->set(array(
      'output' => $userDetails,
      '_serialize' => 'output',
      '_jsonp'=>true
    ));
}
```

Then setup an ajax request from your view.

```
// in your index.ctp's script
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.edit').click(function () {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var userId = $(this).attr('data-id');
            $('#editModal').modal('show');
            $.ajax({
                url:"localhost/your_project/Users/userDetails/"+userId+".json",
                type:'POST',
                success:function(res) {
                    console.log(res); // check the response in your console
                    if(res) {
                        $('#firstname').val(res.firstname);
                        $('#lastname').val(res.lastname);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

You can send the userId as a post data for the function's parameter.

Comment: console.log(res) gives me this error: `POST http://localhost/users/userDetails/2.json 404 (Not Found)` (I clicked the 2nd data entry). Do I need to create a View/ctp file as well to do this, since I have the function in the controller?

Comment: after localhost/ you need to add your project folder name too

Comment: Alright I fixed that bit. When I click the link now, I get the entire page source of the index page inside console, followed by the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'user_firstname' of undefined
    at Object.success (index:192)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at y (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.c (jquery.min.js:4)`, whereby `index:192` refers to `$('#firstname').val(res.User.firstname);` I'll repost this in OP for better formatting.

Comment: did you modify user.firstname to user_firstname?

Comment: Do you mean from `val(res.User.firstname);` to `val(res.User_firstname);`? That fixes the error listed above, but the index.ctp's page source is still shown in the console.log. Additionally, the form inputs are not filled in.

Comment: i dont think the function in controller is returning your response

Comment: Found the issue, was authorisation (I automatically deny access for functions). Upon trying again, I get this error: `POST http://localhost/project/users/userDetails/2.json 500 (Internal Server Error)`. No form inputs are filled in still. I also get this: `XHR Loaded (2.json - 500 Internal Server Error - 411.989000000176ms - 539B)`, and these as sub tabs: `http://localhost/project/users/userDetails/2.json` & 
`VM2658:3 Object {startedDateTime: "2017-03-19T03:57:57.798Z", time: 411.989000000176, request: Object, response: Object, cache: Object…}`

Comment: ummm is your project folder name project?

Comment: Yes. I use PHP variables passed through the AppController that represent the host ($host) and project name ($basepath) (so if I move host or duplicate the project with a different name, it's still useable). So putting `URL: "<?php $host.$basepath ?>/users/userDetails/"+userId+".json"` gives me `http://localhost/project/users/userDetails/2.json` when clicking on the modal for the 2nd data entry.

Comment: If I don't use the PHP variables and just set `url: "userDetails/"+userId+".json"`, I get the same resulting url, and also the same error.

Comment: 500 internal server error means the problem is server side. So I suggest you take a look at your controller. Maybe the AuthComponent is not allowing the function to run?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138437/discussion-between-rik-esh-and-mistaq).